# Webdriver for ipad web applications?

Tags: xcode, ipad, automated-tests, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

How do you setup webdriver in x-code to write automated tests for your webapp?

Answer (score 1):

Instructions on how to set it up are on the [iPhone Driver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/IPhoneDriver) page and more information related to the Mobile Driver can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverForMobileBrowsers